# Need help solving this

Tags: trigonometry

Can I have help with this? I can't think of a way to get started...Thank you

> a) If $k$ and $\alpha$ are constants and  the following trigonometric
>   equation can be solved, 
>   $$2(\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha)\cos\theta+4(\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha)\sin\theta=k$$
>   Prove that $k^2\le32$.
>
> b) If $k=2\sqrt2$, and $-1\le\cot \alpha\le 7$, show that the above
>   equation can be solved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyv9x.jpg

Comment: Correct the link.

Comment: @openspace  done :-)

Comment: Linking images of text is usually frowned upon. Do you know how to use LaTeX?

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff  actually no

Comment: @user348553 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference mathjax resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

For part (a)

$$2(\cos (\alpha) +\sin(\alpha))\cos \theta + 4(\cos \alpha - \sin \alpha)\sin(\theta) = k$$

By harmonic addition theorem, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html

I can express the  $a \cos \theta + b \sin \theta$ in the form of  $R cos(\theta + \delta)$ where $R^2=a^2+b^2$.

\begin{align}R^2 &= 4(\cos (\alpha) + \sin(\alpha))^2+16(\cos \alpha - \sin \alpha)^2\\&=4+4\sin(2\alpha)+16-16\sin(2\alpha)\\
&=20-12\sin(2\alpha)
\leq 32\end{align}

Hence $k^2 \leq 32$.

For part (b)

$$2(\cos (\alpha) +\sin(\alpha))\cos \theta + 4(\cos \alpha - \sin \alpha)\sin(\theta) = 2\sqrt{2}$$

$$sign(2(\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha))\sqrt{20-12\sin(2\alpha)}\cos\left(\theta+\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{4(\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha)}{2(\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha)}\right)\right)=2\sqrt{2}$$

$$\cos\left(\theta+\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{4(\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha)}{2(\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha)}\right)\right)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{sign(2(\cos(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha))\sqrt{20-12\sin(2\alpha)}}$$

**Homework: check that the denominator is non-zero. If it is zero, handle that case separately.**

Hence the system is solvable if

$$\left| \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{20-12\sin(2\alpha)}}\right| \leq 1$$

which is equivalent to

$$\left| \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5-3\sin(2\alpha)}}\right| \leq 1$$

Note that $5-3\sin(2\alpha) \geq 2$

Comment: Do u mind if I ask the relationship of R and K? Sorry I'm horrible at math

Comment: $R\cos(\theta+\delta) = k$, hence $k^2=R^2\cos^2(\theta+\delta) \leq R^2$.